# With the Monero Wallet GUI is it suppose to start synchronizing every time you open it even after it completed synchronizing the 1st time i opened it?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, blockchain, synchronization

Even though my question(according to stackexchange) appears subjective and is likely to be closed, Im still asking it because its driving me crazy and i just want someone to help me PLEASE.

When I first downloaded Monero for windows(windows 10) and finally opened Monero GUI wallet for for first time it said "waiting on Daemon to finish synchronizing" and at the bottom left showed how many blocks were remaining and finally after leaving my laptop on over night and 12 more hours it was finally finished and the monero that i had sent to the wallet finally showed up. So I was excited and thought that was it. So after being on my laptop for a few more hours i closed the wallet and shutdown the laptop. The next day when I turned my laptop on I opened my Monero GUI wallet only to find it saying AGAIN "waiting on Daemon to finish synchronizing" and the thousands of blocks remaining. So is this normal? Every time you open your wallet it has to start synchronizing all over again?! If so that is just absolutely ridiculous. Can someone FOR THE LOVE OF GOD PLEASE help me fix this problem if it even can be fixed. If it cant can someone point me in the direction of a different desktop monero wallet thats closer and more like Electrum or Exodus? Please can someone help me?!?!?!?!

Comment: That's not normal, it should just continue where it left off. Check your `c:\programdata\bitmonero\lmdb` folder, there should be a 20+GB file in there if you're synced. One day produces about 720 blocks, so that should be all that's required to sync if you've been offline for 1 day. Best would be to start the `monerod` program manually and then you could give us more info on what's happening. Once you start `monerod` type `status` and you should see something like: `Height: 1385550/1385550 (100.0%) on mainnet ...`

Comment: Also, where do you save your wallet? Is it removable or read-only media?

Comment: I checked where you told me to and there is a file in the lmdb folder called data.mdb and the size of it is 25.5GB. I havent opened my monero GUI wallet today if that makes a difference. As for starting the monerod I will deff do that but it will have to be tomorrow. I will do it and let you know what it says. Thank you for the help and for the info. Ill be back on tomorrow with details. Oh my wallet is saved in windows C:/>Users>Jason>Downloads>Monero-GUI-Win-x64-v0.10.3.1>Monero-gui-0.10.3.1-beta 2> and thats where the monero-wallet-gui.exe is and a whole lot of other files.IDK if its remova

Comment: OK, so your 25GB file means you got almost the whole blockchain, mine is 27.5GB. Once you start `monerod` you should get a clear idea on what's happening. Now, wallet is a separate thing, it talks to `monerod` who has the blockchain, and asks it to check where your funds are. A full wallet sync takes less than an hour. I think you're almost there, just start `monerod` and keep it running. When you see `SYNCHRONIZED OK`, start the GUI. If you just start the GUI it happens in the background, but this way you get more info. Try doing this for speed-up: https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/5902/57

Answer (score 1):

**You need to sync only the amount that was not synced since the last time you used it.**

If, for example, you used Monero on Monday and then used it again on Wednesday, you would only need to sync the difference. You should not need to start over each time you open the wallet.