# Error on initial monero daemon start with *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL

Tags: error-log, daemon, windows

I just installed and started up the daemon on windows and im getting the error:

```
19192   INFO    global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
Height: 47601/1388220 (3.4%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 895.47 kH/s, v1, up to date, 8(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 1m 21s
```

Comment: What makes you think it is an error ? Many people somehow think it is, but the wording is clear it isn't. Is is just seeing a word without reading the context ? Something else ?

Comment: Says warning and fatal, but yes thats correct as we don't know what its referring to which is why I thought it was an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not an error. Looks normal to me :)
The first line is starting with INFO, and it's just telling you which kind of events will get logged.

Also, I suggest creating a shortcut to monerod.exe, and adding `--block-sync-size 10` to it, as below. Seems to be a cure-all for slow sync.

[image]

Comment: what does that option do?

Comment: Makes you download the blockchain in smaller chunks (of 10 blocks) instead of default 200.